Will I be forced by the Xbox Store to buy an expensive Ubisoft+ subscription, or is there a way around it?
I was thrilled by the trailer for "Anno 1800" and "The Settlers".
I then wanted to buy the game from the Xbox Store, but was very surprised that it costs so much and that Ubisoft+ subscription is compulsory. What disadvantages do I have if I don't do Ubisoft+? Is the game only partially usable without the Ubisoft+ subscription, or not at all?
Can someone explain the situation with "Anno 1800" and "The Settlers" on Xbox?


Sorry, but I am generally against monthly/annual payments. I would like to pay once and then own the whole game in this version.

I don't think you need Ubisoft+ subscription, it seems that you'll have access to both games if you own that. But you can purchase them without that subscription: you can subscribe -OR- buy the game as usual.

I know for "Anno 1800" that you are able to buy/play it without Ubisoft+. I think it should be the same with "The Settlers".
